# Como alterar o valor de um input type text para um formato de data no Laravel

Tags: laravel

O problema é que o input type text está enviando o valor da data para o Banco de Dados Mysql no seguinte formato DD/MM/YYYY, porém o Mysql só aceita um texto para o formato data se estiver no seguinte formato YYYY-MM-DD ou YYYYMMDD.

Código do meu input:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('birth_date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="birth_date" id="input-birth_date" placeholder="Informe sua data de nascimento" type="text" value="{{ old('birth_date') }}" required autofocus>
```

Código da variavel na função pessoa:

```
    protected $fillable = [
    'birth_date',
];
```

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, você pode definir o tipo do input como date

```
<input type="date" class="form-control datepicker form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('birth_date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="birth_date" id="input-birth_date" value="{{ old('birth_date') }}" required autofocus/>
```

Caso você não queira desta forma, no validador você pode colocar o validador 
date_format (`date_format:Y-m-d`) e depois fazer uma formatação de data manual (utilize o boot para automatizar).

Dentro do seu modelo você pode tentar fazer assim

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function (AccountCreation $item) {
        $date = date_create($item->birth_date); 
        $item->birth_date = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    });
}
```

Referência: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-date-format
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287823/validating-a-custom-date-format-in-with-laravel-validator
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35907641/laravel-model-boot-creating-not-firing

Comment: O seguinte erro me é apresentado: `Argument 1 passed to App\People::App\{closure}() must be an instance of App\AccountCreation, instance of App\People given, called in C:\wamp64\www\SIGASS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php on line 347`

Comment: AccountCreation -> coloque a classe do seu modelo!